# How do I update Wagtail for my Shopify store connected website?

Tags: wagtail, updating

I’m looking for support in UPDATING our version of WAGTAIL, which we use in connection with our Shopify store. I do not know where to begin with this as i cant get hold of the person who built the site initially.
The site is [www.101p100.com](http://www.101p100.com) and all the content from wagtail is no longer loading when you launch the site. I assume this is due to having an old version of wagtail.
Please let me know if anyone can help! Thank you so much !

I have read through wagtails article regarding updating the version. But i do not know where to find the relevant place in the code to update the version.  https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/releases/upgrading.html